# Ember-data JSON structure

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have 5 models in some relations:

```
App.Service = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  service_prices: DS.hasMany('servicePrice')
});

App.ServicePrice = DS.Model.extend({
  unit_price: DS.attr('number'),
  qty_unit: DS.belongsTo('qtyUnit'),
  service: DS.belongsTo('service'),
  partner:DS.belongsTo('partner')
});

App.Partner = DS.Model.extend({
    "name": DS.attr('string')
});

App.QtyUnit = DS.Model.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin, {
  name: DS.attr('string'),

});

App.Order = DS.Model.extend({
  service: DS.belongsTo('service'),
  unit_price: DS.attr('numeric'),
  qty_unit:DS.belongsTo('qtyUnit')
});
```

I try to load an order with the following JSON:

```
var order = {
  "order" : {"id":1,"service":1,"qty_unit":4,"unit_price":10},
  "service":[{"id":1,"name":"ENG-GER","service_prices":[1,2]}],
  "servicePrices":[
    {"id":1,"qty_unit":4,"unit_price":3,"partner":1},
    {"id":2,"qty_unit":5,"unit_price":4,"partner":1}
  ],
  "qtyUnits":[
    {"id":4,"name":"character"},
    {"id":5,"name":"word"},
    {"id":6,"name":"sentence"}   
  ],
  "partner":[
    {"id":1,"name":"Jessie Bains"}  
  ]  

};
```

But im getting the following error:

**Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot read property 'deserialize' of undefined**

Is my Json wrong structured?

Here is the JsBin:

### http://jsbin.com/finahuna/12/edit

Answer (score 1):

When requesting records, the relationships in the json should be plural (`services`, `partners`)

```
var order = {
  "order" : {"id":1,"service":1,"qty_unit":4,"unit_price":10},
  "services":[{"id":1,"name":"ENG-GER","service_prices":[1,2]}],
  "servicePrices":[
    {"id":1,"qty_unit":4,"unit_price":3,"partner":1},
    {"id":2,"qty_unit":5,"unit_price":4,"partner":1}
  ],
  "qtyUnits":[
    {"id":4,"name":"character"},
    {"id":5,"name":"word"} 
  ],
  "partners":[
    {"id":1,"name":"Jessie Bains"}  
  ]  

};
```

Additionally your jsbin isn't working per say because:

`services` and `qtyUnits` didn't exist in the scope (possibly you debugging)

```
return Ember.RSVP.hash({
  order:store.find('order',1),
  services: store.all('service'),
  qtyUnits: store.all('qtyUnit')
});
```

If your controller has an object backing it is needs to extend `ObjectController` not `Controller`

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/wimoz/1/edit